# $E(X\mid X\lt x)$ with $X\sim\text{Exp}(a)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X\sim\text{Exp}(a)$.

How do I calculate $E(X\mid X\lt x)$?

---

Workings: 
\begin{align}E(X|X<x)&=\int_0^txf(x|x<x)dx\\
&=\frac{\int_0^txP(x,x<x)dx}{\int_0^tP(x<x)dx}\\
&=\frac{\int_0^txP(x<x)dx}{\int_0^tP(x<x)dx}\\
&=\frac{\int_0^txae^{-ax}dx}{\int_0^tae^{-ax}dx}\\
&=\frac{e^{at}-1-at}{(e^{at}-1)a}
\end{align}

Comment: Please try to improve your notation.  What on earth does $P(x<x)$ mean?

Comment: Jim: Do not hide your work.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct, except of the interchanged roles of $t$ and $x$ (you computed $\mathbb{E}(X\mid X\lt t$)).

---

Heuristically, expected value of $X$ given $A$ is the mean value of $X$ averaged over $A$, i.e. $$\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)=\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}\int_A X \,\text{d}\mathbb{P}.$$

Thus, in this case $(A=\{X\lt x\})$ we are looking for $\frac{1}{F_X(x)}\int_0^xtae^{-at}\,\text{d}t,$ where $F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x)=\mathbb{P}(X\lt x)$ is cumulative distribution function of $X$.

Comment: @Kuba $P(A)$ is not defined, this should be $P(X\in A)$.

Comment: Notice that your denominator also is not just a pdf. You integrated pdf over the interval $[0,x]$ (by the way, $x,t$ still remain incorrectly interchanged), which is the same as if you were integrating either over $(-\infty,x)$ or $(-\infty,x]$ in the case of exponential distribution of $X$. Since the latter is just the cdf evaluated at $x$, our denominators are the same.
@Did You are perfectly right, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Jim Your lines above are sheer nonsense. What does $P(x<x)$ mean?

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand intermediate steps of your calculation, e.g. what is $P(x, x\lt x)$? However, the answer, i.e. $\frac{\int_0^xtae^{-at}dt}{\int_0^xae^{-at}dt}$, is exactly what we are looking for.

Comment: I am trying to do this with notation which resembles one you are familiar with, but it seems I am not able to. Maybe we'll try this way: what is your definition of $\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)$?

Comment: @Jim Aaaargh... $\langle$Faints$\rangle$.

Comment: My understanding of topic is as follows. For an arbitrary $A$ s.t. $\mathbb{P}(A)\gt 0$ the function $\mathbb{P}_A=\mathbb{P}(\cdot\mid A)$ is a probability measure on $\Omega$. One can define the conditional value of $X$ given $A$ as an integral of $X$ w.r.t. this measure, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X\mid A)=\int_\Omega X \,\text{d} \mathbb{P}_A$. Then the formula which I used in my answer happens to be an easy to check corollary from the definition. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ take the value of $X$ only for values less than $x$, otherwise let $Y$ take the value $0$.
The solution is then to find $E[Y]$.

Now,

$P(Y > y) = P(X > y|X < x) = \large\frac{P(y < X < x)}{P(X < x)} = \frac{F_{X}(x) - F_{X}(y)}{F_{X}(x)},$

$\implies f_Y(y) =  \large\frac{f_{X}(y)}{F_{X}(x)},$

$\implies E[Y] = \large\int_{y}\frac{y f_{X}(y)}{F_{X}(x)} dy = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{y f_{X}(y)}{F_{X}(x)} dy,$

$\implies E[Y] = \large\frac{1}{1-e^{-ax}}\int_{0}^{x}y ae^{-ay} dy = \large\frac{1}{1-e^{-ax}}\frac{1-e^{-ax}(ax+1)}{a} = \large\frac{e^{ax}-1-ax}{(e^{ax}-1)a}$.

Comment: The notation $Y=X\mid X\lt x$ is not referring to anything meaningful. On a page where one big problem is *notations*, this is unfortunate.

Comment: @Jim As mentioned by others, you should first and foremost try to get rid of the monstrosities $f(x\mid x)$, $P(x,x\lt x)$ and $P(x\lt x)$. For example, which quantity are you thinking about when you write $P(x, x\lt x)$?